# Publish Python code for data analysis and reference it in PhD Thesis

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have a general question concerning "publishing" python code and referencing it later in my own PhD thesis. I hope someone can provide helpful thoughts about it.
My plan: 
During my PhD time I have written several code snippets for time-frequency analysis. These are not large code projects, but snippets that provide functionalities, which are not included in the general `scipy.signal` package. In approximately 6 month I will hand in the thesis, so now I am thinking about what stuff to include in the thesis. If I include these snippets in my thesis I somehow thought it would be "cooler" to have them already "published" in any form instead of just putting the code in the appendix of the thesis. By doing so I might be able to write something like this in my thesis: `The code for analysing the data_x_y is also available at ...`

I would like to find the easiest way to accomplish this.
Thanks for any comments!

Comment: Why not put it on github?

Comment: I think this is off-topic for SO, but perhaps you're looking for github or similar

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming but about publishing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publish the code on Github. You can optionally create a Python package, and publish that to PyPI.
Once it's on GitHub, you can get a free [DOI for it using Zenodo](https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/). This will create a permanent record (including source code), and makes your code easily citable (both by yourself and others).

Comment: Thank you very much! That sounds interesting. I will definitely have a look at this!